# how to populate excel without error warning using JSONArray and POI

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

Am generating excel using `POI` and am looping an `JSON` Array to fill values in cells
My `JSON` Array structure looks like this

```
[[1,"A","0","6","0","6"],[2,"B","3","3","0","6"],[3,"C","3","0","0","3"],[4,"D","4","0","0","4"],[5,"E","3","6","0","9"],[6,"F","3","6","0","9"],[7,"G","3","3","0","6"],[8,"H","3","0","0","3"],[9,"I","3","3","0","6"],[10,"J","2","0","0","2"],[11,"L","3","0","0","3"],[12,"M","3","0","0","3"],[13,"N","3","0","0","3"],[14,"O","3","0","0","3"],[15,"P","3","0","0","3"],[16,"R","3","0","0","3"]]
```

This Array am looping like this

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
            JSONArray array = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            for(int j=0;j<array.length();j++) {
                Cell  cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(array.getString(j));
            }

}
```

Here the data in the excel is dynamic and it may contain numbers or anything but am printing it to excel like this `cell.setCellValue(array.getString(j))` which is causing an warning like thing in excel (i.e.the number in this cell is preceded by an apostrophe )the excel that gets generated may contain numbers float,String or even doubles.How can I resolve this issue kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Test if your value is a number, and write it as a number rather than a string if so?

Answer (score 1):

The method `Cell.setCellValue()` comes in a number of flavors, i.e. depending on the type of parameter that you pass in, it will create a text-cell, number-cell, boolean or any of the other support types.

As you are passing in a string, POI creates a text-cell in the Excel workbook. If you convert the string to a number (POI uses `double` to allow floating values as well) before populating the cell, it will be written as number-cell which should get rid of the warnings in Excel.

See the [javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28double%29) for details